# Java and JAXB: trying to write a list of mixed objects to xml

Tags: java, list, jaxb, jaxb2

I'm trying to write a list of different type of objects to xml using JAXB,  without any luck. Is this possible using JAXB ? I need all properties (not only the properties defined by the interface), of all objects, written to my xml file.

In my main class :

```
    List<Itransport> myList = new ArrayList<>();

    Bike b = new Bike();
    b.setSpeed(1);
    b.setColor("yellow");
    myList.add(b);

    Car c = new Car();
    c.setDoors(5);
    c.setSpeed(10);
    myList.add(c);

    Train t = new Train();
    t.setLength(10);
    t.setSpeed(50);
    myList.add(t);

    Transport tr = new Transport();
    tr.setVehicles(myList);

    // save the data
    try {
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Itransport.class);
        Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

        // Write to file
        String homeDir = System.getProperty("user.home");
        String filePath = homeDir + File.separator + "test.xml";
        File f = new File(filePath);
        marshaller.marshal(tr, f);

    } catch (JAXBException ex) {
    }
```

My Interface class:

```
    @XmlRootElement
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public interface Itransport {

        public int getSpeed();
        public void setSpeed(int _Speed);

    }
```

My Collection class:

```
    @XmlRootElement(name="vehicles")
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public class Transport {

        @XmlElement(name="transport", type=Itransport.class)
        List<Itransport> vehicles = new ArrayList<>();

        public List<Itransport> getVehicles() {
            return vehicles;
        }

        public void setVehicles(List<Itransport> vehicles) {
            this.vehicles = vehicles;
        }

    }
```

My Bike class:

```
    @XmlRootElement
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public class Bike implements Itransport{

        private int speed = 0;
        private String color = "";

        @Override
        public int getSpeed() {
            return speed;
        }

        @Override
        public void setSpeed(int _speed) {
            speed = _speed;
        }

        public String getColor() {
            return color;
        }

        public void setColor(String color) {
            this.color = color;
        }

    }
```

The Car and Train classes ar almost the same as the Bike class, but with some other properties.

Does anyone have any idea on how to marshall/unmarshall a list of mixed objects ?

Thanks for any feedback

Comment: "_I'm trying to write a list of different type of objects to xml using JAXB, **without any luck**._" What do you obtain currently? An error (exception)? A bad XML output? What is the expect XML of your example?

Comment: The code throws an exception when trying to create the context class. I would like to save the data as XML file with 1 root element, and the train, car and bike objects as subelements of the rootelement...

Comment: I've tried also to replace the List<Itransport> to  List<Objects> without any luck ... I also found some information on using @XmlMixed, but I can't seem to find any good example on how to use it for this purpose ...

Comment: What is the exception?

Answer (score 0):

Register every object extra to be able to marshal mixed lists

```
JAXBContext res = JAXBContext.newInstance(car.class, train.class, bicycle.class);
```